# Definition of Full Binary Tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

I came upon two resources and they appear to say the basic definition in two ways.

[Source 1](http://gateoverflow.in/122126/full-binary-tree-complete-almost-complete-binary-difference) (and one of my professor) says:

> All leaves are at the same level and all non-leaf nodes have two child nodes.

[Source 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) (and 95% of internet) says:

> A full binary tree (sometimes referred to as a proper or plane binary tree) is a tree in which every node in the tree has either 0 or 2 children.

Now following `Source 2`, [image]

becomes a binary tree but not according to `Source 1` as the leaves are not in the same level.

So typically they consider trees like,

[image]

as `Full Binary Tree`.

I may sound stupid but I'm confused what to believe. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between "Complete binary tree", "strict binary tree","full binary Tree"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359660/difference-between-complete-binary-tree-strict-binary-tree-full-binary-tre)

Comment: @TedHopp, if you go to http://gateoverflow.in/122126/full-binary-tree-complete-almost-complete-binary-difference and see the `Fig 1`, that is what they claim to be FULL binary tree. My question is different I guess.

Comment: What your professor calls a "full binary tree", I would call a "balanced binary tree".

Comment: @GordonLinoff, But for a balanced tree is it necessary that all leaves must be in the same level? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree#/media/File:AVLtreef.svg

Comment: @IU5er . . . Not at the same level, but at the same level or level - 1.  Balanced trees are how most database indexes are implemented, and the consistent height is important for performance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I get what you are saying. I just wanted to say that the first definition does not imply that it's a balanced tree but rather a perfect tree as the answers point out.

Comment: I've got a professor (in addition to [this textbook](http://www.cs.williams.edu/JavaStructures/Welcome.html)) that uses the term "full" to refer to "perfect" binary trees as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three main concepts: (1) Full binary tree (2) Complete binary tree and (3) Perfect binary tree. As you said, **full binary tree** is a tree in which all nodes have either degree 2 or 0. However, a **complete binary tree** is one in which all levels except possibly the last level are filled from left to right. Finally, a **perfect binary tree** is a full binary tree in which all leaves are at the same depth. [For more see the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree)

My intuition for the term **complete** here is that given a fixed number of nodes, a complete binary tree is made by **completing** each level from left to right except possibly the last one, as the number of nodes may not always be of the form 2^n - 1.

Comment: That means they are mixing full with perfect, right?

Comment: @lU5er In your case, yes. However, some may use the term complete to refer to perfect, and instead use "almost complete" to refer to complete as we defined here.

Comment: Fine. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 4):

I think the issue is, what's the purpose of making the definition? Usually, the reason for defining *full binary tree* in the way that appears in Wikipedia is to be able to introduce and prove the [Full Binary Tree Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1846322/29789):

> The total number of nodes *N* in a full binary tree with *I* internal nodes is 2 *I* + 1.

(There are several equivalent formulations of this theorem in terms of the number of interior nodes, number of leaf nodes, and total number of nodes.) The proof of this theorem does not require that all the leaf nodes be at the same level.

What one of your professors is describing is something I would call a *perfect binary tree*, or, equivalently, a *full, complete binary tree*.

Comment: Thanks for your help. :)